# JSON UI Helper or JSON Lint with dropdown suggestions using a JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, lint, json-schema-validator, jsonlint

My client needs to have an USER interface where they can build a JSON
The JSON is defined and validated by its schema

For example, if you could go here https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact

[image]

This editor lets us define the JSON and it displays the dropdown suggestions so the user may not make a mistake.

I have no idea how this is being done?
Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Is there a third party tool available?

https://jsonschemalint.com/#!/version/draft-07/markup/json THis does exactly but it doesnt show a dropdown

Comment: Have you looked at our implementations page? https://json-schema.org/implementations.html  There are a few editors and linters listed you can try.

Comment: That didnt help. There is nothing so far I believe. Thank you so much for the link.